# error when importing ijson module python

Tags: python, json, yajl

I need to parse some large (2 Gb+) files into python. I have tried it with the json module but I get a memory error as its methods all load the files at once. 
I then moved on into installing ijson which suposedly implements a iterator-based way of parsing the file. However when I run:

import ijson

I get exception : YAJL shared object not found.

Has anyone found a similar issue?
any help would be greatly appreciated

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats an easy one, that is because you haven't installed the YAJL C library!
ijson is a wrapper around the YAJL without it won't work.

Comment: Just saw the answer now, Thanks chutsu

Answer (score 0):

I installed it via Anaconda and suddenly it started working.

1. Open Anaconda prompt (win search anaconda)
2. run command: conda install ijson