# Can't import ijson module on python 3.7.0

Tags: python, pip

I have installed python 3.7.0 and my installation directory is AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32

Now I have tried to upgrade pip with:
python -m pip install –upgrade pip'

and I got: 
**Successfully installed pip-19.0.3**

I did pip install ijson(while I was in folder AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts) and double checked with the result being:

**Requirement already satisfied: ijson in c:\users\myusername\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (2.3)**

But when I go to my PyCharm project and I import ijson it can't find the module.Just to be clear if I import json or any other module I can work with it.

I know this has some duplicates and I have seen some of them. I have tried everything for example on these and others. Just for reference ([possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24919536/cannot-import-3rd-party-packages))([possible dublicate 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11485610/error-when-importing-ijson-module-python))

but I haven't been able to solve my issue. Please tell me if I am missing something, maybe it is connected to the interpreter I am using or a wrong installion of python.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the python interpreter you are using in Pycharm is the one where you install ijson via pip.

You can do this by looking at the interpreter path in PyCharm, then opening that path in your terminal and trying `import ijson`

Also make sure the pip you are using is connected to the python interpreter you are using in PyCharm

Comment: So I was using Virtualenv Enviroment. So I changed interpreter to System interpreter (added it) and it worked thank you so much. But I still don't understand exactly how I resolved it.

Comment: You just install `ijson` in the same python environment, which you were using for PyCharm

Comment: So let's say I wanted to use the venv interpreter that means I should install the module in the path of this interpreter in my python folder?

Comment: Yes, use the pip inside the venv interpreter to install the module and point your PyCharm to that